# Отклонение правок пользователем Max ZS

Tags: обсуждение, отклонённые-правки

Предложение: запретить Max ZS рецензировать правки других участников.

[Страница профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200109/max-zs). [Статистика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/87973):

- Max ZS одобрил 18, отклонил 53 и улучшил 0 предлагаемых правок

Для сравнения статистиска опытных проверяющих:

- cheops одобрил 775, отклонил 73 и улучшил 4 предлагаемых правок,
- alexolut одобрил 233, отклонил 41 и улучшил 47 предлагаемых правок,
- Streletz одобрил 516, отклонил 140 и улучшил 51 предлагаемую правку,
- Visman одобрил 515, отклонил 39 и улучшил 1 предлагаемую правку,
- kff одобрил 501, отклонил 74 и улучшил 27 предлагаемых правок,
- Nicolas Chabanovsky одобрил 93, отклонил 3 и улучшил 4 предлагаемых правок,
- Denis одобрил 236, отклонил 42 и улучшил 51 предлагаемых правок,
- Андроид Андроид одобрил 444, отклонил 21 и улучшил 9 предлагаемых правок.

Виден заметный перекос Max ZS в сторону отклонения. [Страница его рецензий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93322), примеры отклонённых правок:

- [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93322),
- [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93539),
- [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93472),
- [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93471),
- [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92974),
- [6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92971),
- [7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92485).

Все они были приняты другими проверяющими.

На мой взгляд действия Max ZS идут вразрез с принятыми в сообществе нормами, и наносят вред Stack Overflow, лишая ресурс потенциально полезных правок.

Но, возможно, у вас другая точка зрения.

Comment: Также сталкивался с подобными правками ([пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92975)) на своем опыте, [спрашивал в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30964319#30964319) каких традиций придерживается сообщество. C одной стороны официально [рекомендуется правки орфографические принимать](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630/), с другой стороны вижу реальную правоприменительную практику, когда новичков прессуют с первого поста, приучают минусами к чистоте.

Comment: @AK, я делаю так: если ошибок меньше трёх — не лезу, больше или же ошибки существенные — исправляю; по вероятностному суждению таких среди всех моих правок где-то треть. Всего у меня 207 одобренных и 10 отклонённых, из чего делаю вывод, что сообщество в целом не возражает против подобных действих. Показанную в Вашем примере правку лично я, конечно, принял бы.

Comment: Может быть это просто период э-э-э... притирки. Все его проходили и в конечном итоге всё же побеждали собственных тараканов.

Comment: Поставил участнику временный запрет на доступ в очереди, дал ссылку на этот пост.

Comment: @PashaPash вы ссылку дали только в комментарии к запрету или где-нибудь ещё?

Comment: @NickVolynkin пока только в комментарии к запрету. Можете продублировать в pm, если считаете нужным.

Comment: Текст «улучшил 51 предлагаемых правок» — явная ошибка в Transifex. Исправил.

Answer (score 15):

## Рубить голову с плеча

Можно спорить про важность правки орфографии, но отклонение [правки №2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93539) (форматирование блока кода) и [правки №1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/93322) (форматирование отрывков кода в тексте) — это вандализм. Правки заметно упрощают чтение вопроса, и если юзер этого не понимает, то в очереди проверок ему делать нечего.

Ещё:

- [8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92082) (исправление отступов в коде)
- [9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92056) (существенное исправление оформления популярного вопроса)
- [10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/91748) (конвертирование кода в исполняемый сниппет)
- [11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/90118) (добавление ссылки на документацию)
- [12](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/89786) (исправление метки)
- [13](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/89620) (исправление бесмысленного заголовка на содержательный)
- [14](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/89621) (исправление метки и существенная правка оформления)
- [15](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/87973) (перенос кода со внешнего сайта)
- [16](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/87820) (форматирование блока кода)
- [17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/87816) (исправление заголовка и меток)

Налицо полное непонимание процесса. Я бы даже сказал, что отсутствие здравого смысла.

---

О(б)суждаемый юзер высказался. Соответственно, остаюсь при своём мнении.

Comment: похоже на просто автоматическое нажатие отклонить сразу

Answer (score 11):

### Предлагаю не рубить сплеча.

> Все они были приняты другими проверяющими.

Значит, **система работает** и в подобных мерах **нет большой необходимости**.

---

А теперь немного лирики.

- Мы **не знаем**, сколько правок в своих проверках он **пропустил**. По характеру отклонённых правок (в которых вреда... "не слишком много") похоже, что очень мало (возможно, ноль).
- Все перечисленные правки отклонены *по одной и той же причине*, **"Не содержит никаких улучшений"**. **Это странно.** Я посмотрел правки и вне выборки, приведённой в вопросе, и там фигурировала та же причина. Возможно, это его "ответ по умолчанию", когда он не уверен, что правка уместна? Если так, похоже, что ему надо рассказать о кнопке <kbd>Пропустить</kbd>.

Исходя из вышесказанного, предлагаю **тревогнуть модератора**, дабы он воспользовался **супер-призывом** и сообщил участнику о потенциально проблемном поведении. И рассказал о кнопке <kbd>Пропустить</kbd>! Я не думаю, что он несёт вред целенаправленно, банальное "не надо так делать" может всё исправить.

---

**PS:** Лирика неактуальна, т. к. обвиняемый высказал свою позицию. Но я оставляю ответ как голосование за "система выдержала, беспокоиться не о чем", хоть сам этот вариант уже не поддерживаю.

Comment: Ну не "все",а "большинство". Пример я привёл в первом же комментарии.

Comment: @AK все **перечисленные в вопросе** правки. Но сути это не меняет, подозрительно много одинаковых вердиктов.

Comment: Вы можете объяснить, как можно выбирать вариант "не содержит улучшений", если перед вашими глазами два варианта оформления кода: месиво в одну строчку и нормальный блок кода? Безо всяких правил, традиций, процесса и прочего — просто с точки зрения здравого смысла?

Comment: @Squidward не могу. Точнее, могу, но обе стороны будут знать, что это притянуто за уши, а узнать реальные мотивы это не поможет. Поэтому я и предлагаю сначала связаться с участником, а уже потом применять санкции.

Comment: Вандализм, имху, налицо, но "сначала поговорить, а потом санкции" кажется более здравым решением. Я читал вопросы и ответы, он явно владеет русским языком и разбирается в программировании. Больше похоже на авторскую позицию: он так считает, а не ошибается. И тем не менее -- лучше сначала поговорить.

Answer (score -6):

Никакого автоматического отклонения нет. Это не притирки и не тараканы - это моя позиция. Отклонял и буду отклонять мелкие правки. Я не ставлю перед собой цель зарабатывать медальки или набирать очки. Это не ресурс по русскому языку и поэтому также не вижу цели исправлять орфографию и пунктуацию. Но если ресурс предлагает мне что-либо к исправлению, то я это рассматриваю, исходя из собственных представлений. Если в общем и целом другие считают иначе - они поступают иначе и в целом мое мнение тогда не учитывается. Таковы правила. Хотите разводить холивар по поводу несостоятельности правил ресурса? Разводите. Хотите меня банить? Да ради Бога, хоть пожизненно. Это ваше право, как и мое право есть отклонять подобные правки.

Мое видение такое, что тот, кто оформляет подобным образом свои вопросы, именно он притирается. И если он останется на ресурсе, то узнает про правила оформления и вернется к своему вопросу. А если нет. То так ему нужен и этот вопрос и этот ресурс.

Также я бы сделал лучше не оценку того, кто и как насколько и что оценил, а оценку того, кто и на чем заработал свою репутацию. А то поднимают осевшее за годы говно и начинают его мутить правкой одной буквы (я знаю, что на мете этот вопрос поднимался). Если защищать таких фразами, мол за какой-то период многое в IT могло поменяться, то давайте давать хоть всплытию таких вопросов, только при условии ответа на них, а не правки метки или пунктуации.

Мой вывод для вас - вот поищите-ка лучше таких, у кого, скажем, больше половины репы заработано правкой меток, орфографии и пунктуации.

Comment: Дальше 2к репы на правках не подымается, если что ;-)  так что сложно обвинить тех, у кого больше 5к репы в том, что они больше половины набрали на правках ;-)

Comment: За правки репу дают? Думал, сугубо альтруисткое занятие.

Comment: @alexis031182 +2 за принятую правку... но это до 2к репы... дальше только бесплатно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , понятно, видимо не обращал внимания. Это ж сколько надо всякого наисправлять, чтобы существенный рейтинг заиметь. Мнение не поменял, этим заниматься ради репы - нонсенс.

Comment: Позиция понятна. Однако, без учета кармических дел, даже от небольших правок есть польза: 1) это поиск ответа через поисковые системы и полнотекстовый поиск по сайту. Если текст написан с ошибками, заголовок не полный или не понятный, то найти пусть даже хороший ответ будет сложно. Да ищут с ошибками, но вероятность того, что ищут с одной и той же ошибкой меньше, чем поиск по правильному запросу 2) Если на сайте много небрежно оформленных вопросов и ответов, это побуждает и других крайне небрежно относиться к оформлению своих вопросов и ответов.

Comment: @cheops, это как раз позиция, озвученная Вами, понятна. Но без учёта кармических дел, тема теряет часть своей привлекательности. Например такое замечательное качество, как зависть, сразу упускается из виду. А ведь это таракан, я бы даже сказал натуральный.

Comment: @alexis031182 Зависть? :) Ну Вы пошутили... Зависть к тем, кто ничего не может кроме как вносить правки? Смешно.

Comment: Плюсую, хоть и не разделяю Вашу точку зрения. Насколько вижу, правил не нарушали, возможность отклонять правки заработали репутацией.

Comment: @cheops Соглашусь с Вам в том, что для нормального поиска правки нужны. Но никак не соглашусь с тем, что небрежное оформление может сподвигнуть к подобному и других. Из своего жизненного опыта я очень четко вынес одну вещь, касающуюся данного момента: если человека в школе обучили нормально русскому языку, то ему будет претить подобная небрежность в написании всю жизнь. И ничто не заставит его на форумах и в мессенджерах коверкать язык, пропускать буквы и знаки пунктуации. Проверено уже и не на одном человеке.

Comment: @MaxZS, а вот и второй - высокомерие. Вот этот самый юркий, недюжинная ловкость нужна, чтоб тапком поймать.

Comment: Хочу отдельно заметить тем, кто подумал, что это автоматически отклонялись правки... Ресурс следит за этим и периодически (я бы даже сказал, что очень часто) проверяет на вшивость. Так используйте этот момент против автоматических отклонений.

Comment: @alexis031182 Да-да. И все это Вы пишите про себя и тех, кого по каким-то непонятным причинам задел тот факт, что я, следуя своим принципам и правилам ресурса, наступил им на больной мозоль. Иначе не понятно, зачем было разводить этот холивар и пытаться оценивать мои личностные качества.

Comment: @alexis031182 почему вас так беспокоит чужое высокомерие? Это личный выбор каждого, неужели это как то затрагивает вашу жизнь?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, это очевидно, потому что сам такой же :)

Comment: @alexis031182 здоровая конкуренция, это же здорово! )

Comment: А вообще, рассмотрите и такой момент... Есть ресурс. На нем есть определенные правила... и своеобразный баланс. Я отклоняю правку, другие ее принимают. Правка проходит. Никто ничего не нарушил. Все работает как необходимо. Но вот незадача. Этот баланс вдруг не устроил нескольких человек (вот миллионы он устраивает, а двух-трех - нет). И они начинают искать и создавать исключения из правил. Именно они пытаются нарушить правила ресурса. И именно они пытаются нарушить тот самый баланс. Но вопреки всему "наказанию" подвергают других, а не их.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, нет никакой конкуренции, минус на минус складывается, если MaxZS брешет. А вот если он реально крут и действительно чертовски принципиален, то этот таракан уже не мой.

Comment: Говорите, что больше 2k репы за правки не поднять? А зачем тогда их некоторые проводят с таким завидным усердием? Так может быть за медальки? Ведь медальки по сути это та же самая репутация в неявном виде. И вот подумайте над тем, что сам ресурс этими медальками провоцирует не работу над вопросами и ответами, а работу над орфографией, пунктуацией и метками.

Comment: @MaxZS, ещё и медали за правки дают?! Мой мир рухнул и никогда не будет прежним...

Comment: @MaxZS, хорошо, на 500 кончаются медальки... дальше можно править со спокойной совестью? :) Правят потому что с таким дурацким названием ответ не найти никогда, потому что ошибки режут глаза, потому что зачастую тупо нельзя понять что спрашивают из-за того, что код не форматирован. Я просто не могу удержаться, когда вижу, что могу сделать текст лучше, понятнее, читабельнее. Вы же в коде тоже самое сделаете, если увидите, что можно написать более элегантно и красиво.

Comment: @alexis031182 И вот еще, что я хотел бы заметить... Пусть даже будет именно по Вашему и я являюсь высокомерным завистником. Тогда возникает вопрос... Вы реально думаете изменить мои личностные качества баном? Или Вы реально хотите баном изменить мою позицию? Смешно и неудобно :)

Comment: @MaxZS, я против того, чтобы Вас банили. И против того, чтобы Вы поменяли свою позицию из-за какого-либо давления извне. Вы конструктивные комментарии публикуете, жаль им не нашлось места в Вашем ответе.

Comment: @alexis031182 Кому действительна интересна данная тема, тот прочитает ее всю и сделает выводы. Кто уже занял свою позицию - тот, с большой долей вероятности, проголосует согласно именно занятой позиции. И ему, в принципе, по барабану будет мое или чье-либо мнение даже после прочтения ответа. Ну а про тех, кто голосует за медальку, я вообще умолчу (не уверен действует ли на мете это правило).

Comment: @alexis031182 Что же касается самого ответа и минусов, ну так здесь вообще все очень и очень просто. Я просто удаляю ответ и вы со своими догадками продолжаете холиварить самостоятельно :) Все кто будут подключаться к теме будут читать только первоначальный вопрос и голосовать "за" или "против", разводя дальнейший холивар по поводу, а был ли бот и каковы его мотивы. Хорошо это или плохо? Не знаю. Но таковы правила :)

Comment: @MaxZS, очень многие, согласно отдельным комментариям, высказались за то, чтобы взять таймаут и посмотреть, что Вы ответите. Я думаю, что таких большинство. И это правильно, поскольку объективность требует. По сему очень важно представить именно конструктивные аргументы в защиту своей позиции и именно в ответе, а не на периферии в комментариях, которые в любой момент ещё и сотрут, ибо не чат и всё такое. Если Вам всё равно - Ваше право, но тогда и цена Вашей позиции соответствующая.

Comment: @alexis031182 Да. Мне все равно, какое решение будет принято. Я просто высказал свою позицию, обратил внимание на то, что я не бот (и на то, что ресурс и без их помощи отслеживает ботов). Я уже сам себя перестаю уважать за то, что вступил в дискуссию, которая скорее напоминает оправдание с моей стороны. Но оправдывается только виноватый. Я же себя таковым не считаю. Я ничего не нарушал. Тем более, сами же пользователи и привели 17 ссылок на примеры моих отклонений. Из 17-и ссылок 16! были по факту приняты. Это говорит о том, что сама система работает. Так зачем вообще эта тема была поднята? :)

Comment: @MaxZS, я вообще не знал, что за правки дают рейтинг, а ещё меня бесило, что если хочется исправить банальную "тся/ться" ошибку система не пускает(изменено меньше 6 символов). Но, это ведь не касается форматирования кода. Даже исходя из Вашей позиции, форматировать код - мелкая правка?

Comment: @MaxZS, всё это затеяно, чтобы дать возможность другим оценить ситуацию объективно. Встать в позу всегда можно успеть, но мне кажется, что всё могло бы повернуться иначе, если бы Вы не рассматривали эту дискуссию непременно с той точки зрения, что всё вертится исключительно вокруг Вас. В комментариях Вы отметили, что именно не устраивает. Это и есть повод для дискуссии. А всякие баны - дело последнее и в целом не интересное.

Comment: @alexis031182 Еще и еще раз... Все вертится не вокруг меня, а вокруг правил ресурса. А кто-то вдруг усомнился в их корректности и решил, что я закрутил всё вокруг себя :) Но ведь это не так. И доказывать это бессмысленно, если человек вбил себе в голову обратное. А что касается бана... Так я же его получил в плане внесения правок. И никто же не стал ждать моего ответа. Т.е. никого, в принципе, не интересовало мое мнение. Просто пошла реакция на чьи-то сопли без реальной оценки даже результатов правок.

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, так запретите вообще отклонять правки - это тогда будет идти в ногу с вашими понятиями. Ведь именно я нарушил эти понятия (замечу, не правила ресурса). Я оказался просто не таким, как другие. Ведь именно так и ставился вопрос: `На мой взгляд действия Max ZS идут вразрез с принятыми в сообществе нормами, и наносят вред Stack Overflow, лишая ресурс потенциально полезных правок.` Так в чем, собственно вред? Где же те правки, которых я лишил ресурс? :) Странно, не правда ли, но, как оказывается и вреда-то нет. И правки все приняты...

Comment: @MaxZS, у вас забавная позиция. Когда вас спрашивают, почему вы отменяли абсолютно корректные, необходимые и заметно улучшающие сообщения правки, то звучит какая-то странная комбинация аргументов: "У меня такое мнение, что мелкие правки не нужны, кроме того они приняты, значит, система работает". Противоречие получается. Так это мелкие правки или нет? Нужные или нет? Система работает благодаря или вопреки вам?

Comment: @Squidward А всё довольно просто. Моя позиция такова, как я ее описал. Да. Я против мелких правок. И да, правила работают. В чем забавность? Я разве написал, что я против существующих правил? Я разве поднял вопрос (подобный текущему) с целью выкосить мелкие правки. Нет, и еще раз нет. Единственное, с чем я согласен, так это с доводом, приведенным cheops о том, что подобные правки помогают улучшить поиск по сайту (хотя это тоже далеко не всегда так).

Comment: *"Мой вывод для вас - вот поищите-ка лучше таких, у кого, скажем, больше половины репы заработано правкой меток, орфографии и пунктуации"* — Поищите, желаю успехов. :) Подсказка: вот [список активных редакторов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor). Средняя репа — 10000, порог для репы за правки — 2000. :)

Comment: @Squidward И для Вас еще раз отдельно напишу... Форматирование кода неопытный пользователь со временем произведет сам. Научите его это делать, а не подтирайте ему одно место.

Comment: @Squidward комментарии Вы не осилили... Ну и флаг Вам в руки. :)