# Пересмотр решения по предлагаемой правке

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, предлагаемые-правки

Из [комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3386/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-max-zs#comment10751_3386) в соседнем вопросе посмотрел на [отклоненную правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92975). По сути можно сказать, что она была отклонена незаслуженно. Проверяющий приложил усилия и действительно сделал текст лучше для восприятия.

Хотелось бы знать, есть ли на сайте механизм пересмотра решения по предлагаемым правкам? Если его нет, то наверное было бы неплохо иметь такой.

Comment: [Да так и оспариваются, в чате или на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2663/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA?rq=1#comment8288_2663).

Comment: @СашаЧерных это лишние телодвижения на самом деле, по таким случаям в чат или на мету переходить.

Comment: В случае отклонения моей правки я обращаюсь лично к участникам, отклонившим правку, где-нибудь в их старых вопросах, [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484988/199934), дабы не тревожить сообщество по каждой мелочи, да и более конструктивно это с моей стороны. Когда же действия, не вызывающие у меня одобрения, носят массовый систематический характер, — как в соседнем вопросе, — обращаюсь сюда. // Не считаю, что чего-то недостаёт и нужен какой-то дополнительный механизм.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, а что даст такое личное обращение к участникам? Нельзя самостоятельно изменить своё же принятое решение по правке.

Comment: Если обсуждение конструктивное и аргументированное, оно всегда что-то даёт. Есть шанс выяснить, где ты чего-то недопонял, а когда они. Решение изменить нельзя, но если сумели договориться, можно попросить проверяющего принять правку, внесённое в то же сообщение.

Comment: Хотя правку откатили мне -- я не стал подавать на апелляцию - ни лично уточнять, ни на мете. Если бы мне системно ставили минуса, наверное и имело бы смысл возмущаться (у меня на сегодня > 90% правок принято). А вот соседний вопрос именно о систематичном отклонении вразрез мнению большинства редакторов.

Comment: На мой взгляд, правка отклонена заслуженно, потому что сообщение всё ещё представляет из себя слабосвязанную свалку из слов без форматирования и требует более серьёзной переработки. А поскольку это оффтопик, возможно, и удаления, делать вычитку такого контента в целом смысла мало. Т. е.: объём исправляемых этой правкой проблем на фоне общего объёма -- капля в море.

Answer (score 3):

Собственно предложения:

1. обеспечить доступ к списку не единогласно утвержденных/отклоненных правок (например, добавить соответствующую секцию на страницу [Проверка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review));
2. обеспечить возможность пометить такую правку как требующую пересмотра;
3. для принятия результатов повторного голосования можно увеличить минимальное кол-во голосов.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history вот эту страничку вы видели уже?

Comment: @NickVolynkin конечно. Но это вся история и там нет возможности сортировки или фильтрации, чтобы получить список интересуемых правок. Также нет инструмента для повторного предложения отклоненной правки, т.е. чтобы вручную ее не повторять.